# Symfony2 file and directory convention

Tags: symfony

Am learning Symfony2 framework. the structure of files and directories make me very annoyed. 
It make me really hard to follow things ej:

```
routing_dev.yml  //use underscore
AppCache.php   // use camel case
```

there is no unique convention.

Can anyone tell me when to use camel case and when to use underscore-separator in the framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP files containing classes follow camel case convention as they follow [PSR-0 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

All the other files, like configurations or scripts, are lower cased.

Somehow I never found it confusing.